# wkhtmltopdf while convert html to pdf getting JavaScript execution exceeded timeout exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the following code for convert html content to pdf.

```
wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --stop-slow-scripts --debug-javascript sau_rec.html test_1.pdf
```

In this html file have a table with more than 1000 rows(tr tag), i am using java script code to avoid page-break issue.

while execute this i am getting the following warning.
Warning: A slow script was stopped
Warning: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4 JavaScript execution exceeded timeout.

Note : if less than 1000 rows its work fine.

any one know solution for this please update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --no-stop-slow-scripts  sau_rec.html test_1.pdf
```